# Animate on setTimeOut without CSS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, animation

Well i don't know if this is even possible but i'm triying to trigger an animation using javascript on setTimeout without using css or jquery because i need to put it on a JS file from another source and has to work everywhere... (i'm having a headache right now) i made this

```
setTimeout(function() {
var cuadro = document.getElementById('cuadro');
if (cuadro) { cuadro.style.marginLeft = 0}  
}, 2000 );
```

and indeed moves it an element from margin-left: 400 to 0 on 2 seconds but i want to ease that animation

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Using `requestAnimationFrame` would really be nicest for this. Maybe the timeout as a fallback for IE9 and before. Any particular reason to not use a CSS translate?

Comment: >: yup, this is for a tab on a chatsystem that works only with js, this just display the tab changing the .style.display from none to block when the invite obj is active

Comment: Small detail - the `if` statement in the answer needed one more increment for it to not miss the last step. Just being thorough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEgjpZ

```
var i = 0, cuadro = document.getElementById('cuadro');
if (cuadro) cuadro.style.marginLeft = 0;

animationFrames();

function animationFrames() {

  if (i <= 80) {
  cuadro.style.marginLeft = i*5 + 'px';
  i++;
  setTimeout(animationFrames, 25);
  }
}
```